# OpenCV java - VideoCapture.read from a url always returns false

Tags: java, opencv

So I have a RTMP server set up at `127.0.0.1:1935`, my program works just fine with local videos, but it won't fetch a frame from the live stream

```java
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

        VideoCapture fromUrl = new VideoCapture("rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/test001");
        Mat image = new Mat();

        System.out.println(fromUrl.read(image)); // Always false


        VideoCapture local = new VideoCapture("D:\\a.mp4");
        System.out.println(local.read(image));  // Always true

    }
}
```

If I rewrite the same code in python, it just works:

```py
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/test001")
err, frame = cap.read()
print(frame.shape, frame)
```

```
(1080, 1920, 3)
[[[33 29 32]
  [33 29 32]
  [33 29 32]
  ...
  [28 31 31]
  [27 30 30]
  [28 31 31]]]
[flv @ 000001dc17742d40] unsupported amf type 17
```

Here is what I get when I use `Core.getBuildInformation()` (removed redundant imformation)

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.6.0 =====================================
  Version control:               4.6.0

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2022-06-05T15:49:50Z
    Host:                        Windows 10.0.16299 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.20.21032501-MSVC_2
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64
    CMake build tool:            MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1900
    Configuration:               Debug Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (16 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (4 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (31 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2

OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc java ml objdetect photo python2 stitching video videoio
    Disabled:                    python3 world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 ts
    Applications:                apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI:                           WIN32UI
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.12)
    JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.1.2-62)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.2.0)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.4.0)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      avcodec:                   YES (58.134.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.76.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.70.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.9.100)
      avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            YES
      DXVA:                      NO

  Parallel framework:            Concurrency

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
           at:                   C:/build/master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
              at:                C:/build/master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.19.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (NVD3D11)
    Include path:                C:/build/master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

Java:                          
    ant:                         C:/utils/soft/apache-ant-1.10.12/bin/ant.bat (ver 1.10.12)
    JNI:                         C:/utils/soft/jdk1.8.0_333/include C:/utils/soft/jdk1.8.0_333/include/win32 C:/utils/soft/jdk1.8.0_333/include
    Java wrappers:               YES
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    C:/build/master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static/install
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Classpath:

```
...
D:\FFmpeg\bin
D:\opencv\build\bin
```

VLC can watch the stream normally, too.

So I have 2 questions:

1. How can I make it capture the frame?
2. What can I do with `[flv @ 000001dc17742d40] unsupported amf type 17`?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Alright I figured it out, I need to add `D:\opencv\build\bin` to vmoptions